# Key error while performing simplification on an expression

Tags: python, sympy

When I attempt to perform simplification, using `sympy.simplify`, on the following expression :

```
0.0625*v**2*cos(0.5*u)**2 + (-0.25*v*sin(0.5*u)*sin(u) + (0.5*v*cos(0.5*u) + 1)*cos(u))**2 + (-0.25*v*sin(0.5*u)*cos(u) - (0.5*v*cos(0.5*u) + 1)*sin(u))**2
```

I get the error :

```
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy-0.7.7.dev0-py2.7.egg/sympy/simplify/fu.pyc in f(rv)
   1323                         key = cos(a*cc, evaluate=False)
   1324                         ccs.append(cc)
-> 1325                         take = min(coss[key], take or coss[key])
   1326                     # update exponent counts
   1327                     for i in range(k):

KeyError: cos(1.0*u)
```

What seems to be the issue here ? The expression it self seems quite straight forward.

**Edit 1:**

Just for the sake of clarity, this is the culprit :

```
simplify(expr)
```

where `expr` is the above expression.

**Edit 2:**

Here is the code that generates the error :

```
from sympy import cos,sin, simplify
from sympy.abc import u,v
expr = 0.0625*v**2*cos(0.5*u)**2 + (-0.25*v*sin(0.5*u)*sin(u) + (0.5*v*cos(0.5*u) + 1)*cos(u))**2 + (-0.25*v*sin(0.5*u)*cos(u) - (0.5*v*cos(0.5*u) + 1)*sin(u))**2
simplify(expr)
```

Comment: How about breaking line 1325 into smaller bits, so you can see more clearly what the error is? E.g. Have you tried evaluating 'coss[key]' by itself? How about 'take or coss[key]'?

Comment: That is the Sympy library, and not my own code. I simply pasted the last link in the error message.

Comment: So how about editing your question to show some of your actual code (specifically a miminal, executable, verifiable subset,. not just a line that gives an error), not the library code, then?

Comment: This looks like a bug. You should report it on the SymPy issue tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing cos(u) with cos(1.0*u) works, but do not ask me why…

```
expr = 0.0625*v**2*cos(0.5*u)**2 + (-0.25*v*sin(0.5*u)*sin(u) + (0.5*v*cos(0.5*u) + 1)*cos(1.0*u))**2 + (-0.25*v*sin(0.5*u)*cos(1.0*u) - (0.5*v*cos(0.5*u) + 1)*sin(u))**2
```

But then simplify returns the same result. I think sympy cannot mix symbolic computations with floats.

```
expr = v**2*cos(u/2)**2/16 + (-v*sin(u/2)*sin(u)/4 + (v*cos(u/2)/2 + 1)*cos(u))**2 + (-v*sin(u/2)*cos(u)/4 - (v*cos(u/2)/2 + 1)*sin(u))**2
```

seems to work, and returns :

```
v**2*cos(u/2)**2/4 + v**2/16 + v*cos(u/2) + 1
```

If you want to convert an existing expression :

```
import sympy
from sympy import cos,sin, simplify
from sympy.abc import u,v
import re
expr = 0.0625*v**2*cos(0.5*u)**2 + (-0.25*v*sin(0.5*u)*sin(u) + (0.5*v*cos(0.5*u) + 1)*cos(u))**2 + (-0.25*v*sin(0.5*u)*cos(u) - (0.5*v*cos(0.5*u) + 1)*sin(u))**2

def ratio_from_float(m):
    a,b = float(m.group(0)).as_integer_ratio()
    return '({0}/{1})'.format(a,b)

def convert(expr):
    return sympy.expr.sympify(re.sub('\d+\.\d+',ratio_from_float,str(expr)))

print(simplify(convert(expr)))
```

Comment: The reason why float aren't handled by sympy might be that they are unlikely to be exact enough to be simplified

Comment: That is true, but it doesn't explain the key error, which is a bug.

Comment: Indeed it works! However, your solution does not solve my issue entirely. That expression is generated by SymPy. Hence before I can evaluate the expression using simplify, I have to search for all float expressions in SymPy functions (like cosine) and replace them with rational numbers (given the float can be represented as a rational number).

Comment: Could you give the code that gives that to you ? If you have a string, searching for those expressions isn't complicated with the re module, and you can easily get the job done with float.as_integer_ratio.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem using your answer. My real intention was to perform a coordinate transformation for the Mobius strip :   `x = (1 + cos(u/2.)*v/2.)*cos(u); y = (1 + cos(u/2.)*v/2.)*sin(u); z = sin(u/2.)*v/2.` . This is a habit of mine, to avoid integer division.  So, I replaced the float `2.` with integer `2`, and the transformation worked just fine! Where the expression in this post becomes the first entry of the metric.

Comment: Yes, it is very annoying. Have you considered switching to Python 3 ? I made all my tests with it, and sympy seems to work fine. There is distinct operators for float and integer divisions.
Look at my edited answer, I made the converting function.